# Problems with oil furnace

Tags: heating

Why does my oil furnace keep triping reset after 10 sec of running i have to have thermostat all way up for it to run i changed primary control box, nozzel, electrodes and thermostat any ideas

Comment: Have you changed the flame sensor? Are the pumps or fans running OK?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons an oil furnace will trip out. The control box is looking at Flame, draft, fuel supply, water levels in a FHW system, heat exchanger (water) temps, fan function (FHA)  fyreye, etc. A problem with a circulator pump will cause an water high temp shutdown for example.  A one hour service call from a licensed tech probably would have cost less than replacing a bunch of parts that are not the problem.  My advice is always to consult a pro unless one is equipped with the knowledge and tools to do the job.